# Create a new table out of an existing one

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, create-table

I am having this table of words from multiple files. I want to count how many files each word shows. I can that with the piece of code below. But when I nest it with the CREATE TABLE statement, it won't work. The second piece of code below is the error code.

```
SELECT WORD, COUNT(*) FROM (select DISTINCT ABSTRACTID, WORD FROM NSFABSTRACTS)
GROUP BY WORD ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE DOC_FREQ (WORD, TOTALCOUNT) AS
(
  SELECT WORD, COUNT(*) FROM (select DISTINCT ABSTRACTID, WORD FROM NSFABSTRACTS)
  GROUP BY WORD ORDER BY COUNT(*));
```

Here is the error message:
`SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:

*Action:`
Can anyone suggest how to create this table? Thanks.

Comment: What error does it get? ORA-00907?

Comment: You're also still tagging in a way that limits how many people will see your posts. I've changed a couple of your previous questions to be tagged with just 'oracle'. This is nothing to do with SQL Developer really, that is just the client you happen to be using, but it has no bearing on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `order by` when you have the query enclosed in parentheses; at least if that clause is also within the parentheses:

```
create table t42 as (select * from dual order by dummy);

SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

It is allowed outside:

```
create table t42 as (select * from dual) order by dummy;

table T42 created.
```

You can remove the parentheses as they aren't needed at all here:

```
create table t42 as select * from dual order by dummy;

table T42 created.
```

Or remove the `order by`, since an `order by` in the `create` statement [usually makes little difference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54628) and doesn't affect how the data is retrieved:

```
create table t42 as (select * from dual);

table T42 created.
```

Or preferably for my tastes, both:

```
create table t42 as select * from dual;

table T42 created.
```